# Objective -c: Need some explanation on the following code regarding dispatch_async (GCD)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, thread-sleep

Basically the code below works as follows, when I push a button it causes both labels to update in 4 seconds with its respected text at same time. However, if I comment out       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){ my labels still update but it will take first label 4 second then the second label updates 4 seconds later after the first label. I am wondering if someone can explain why both labels update in 4 seconds with the dispatch code in a dumb down matter so to speak. I try listening to the tutorial explanation, but it just confused me even more.

```
void (^tFunct1)(UILabel *,NSString*) = ^(UILabel *lbl, NSString *src){
 NSLog(@"GO TO SLEEP...");
 sleep(4);
 NSLog(@"WAKING UP...");
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
[lbl setText:src];
NSLog(@"Label Done!");
});

};
 -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
aConCurrentQue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0);
dispatch_async(aConCurrentQue ,^{ tFunct1(self ->lblOne, @"1 GO!" ); } );
dispatch_async(aConCurrentQue ,^{ tFunct1(self ->lblTwo, @"2 GO!" ); } );
 }
```

Comment: Seems odd to use a block to call a block from within a block.  Just use a method instead.   Also, using `->` to access ivars works, but is not standard convention.  Just use 'em directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always must do UI updates on the main queue. By commenting out the dispatch to the main queue, you're trying to do UI updates on a background global queue, which explains the incorrect behavior.

UIKit is not designed (with a few very specific exceptions) to work on the background queue and you simply should not be updating the UI on a background queue.

Comment: Cool, also just to be clear dispatch main Que is basically handle by processors kind of like multithreading, correct? Sorry, if I sound ignorant in any way. Been trying to get a grip on this subject for a while.

Comment: @SquidwardTennisballs The main queue is a special serial queue that executes tasks on your app's main thread. See the [About Dispatch Queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW2) section of the _Concurrency Programming Guide._ Because the main queue is so critical for timely UI updates, that's why we dispatch anything slow to a background queue, to not block this main queue. But, like we said above, UI updates must take place on this main queue.

Comment: Cool, so use the background que for anything like downloading or parsing images that usually takes forever.

Comment: @SquidwardTennisballs Correct.